# asp.net regex for all A-Z a-Z numbers spaces and ! " ' but not accented characters

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am having a number of issues with my reg ex

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSmsMessage" Font-Names="" Font-Size="Small" runat="server" Width="450px" Name="txtSmsM" Height="150px" Style="margin-left: 50px; resize: none;" Value="Enter SMS" MaxLength="160" TextMode="MultiLine" onkeypress="return taLimit(this)" onkeyup="return taCount(this,'myCounter')" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="x" runat="server" ErrorMessage="you have inputted incorect charicters" ControlToValidate="txtSmsMessage" ValidationExpression="@'^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+$'" />
```

The current one `@'^[a-zA-Z0-9\!` will not find ! or spaces

Basically I need a reg ex for numbers letters and special characters but what to stop things like ë, the input box as you can see if for a sms message and character like ë error with our sms sending provider, thanks Mike

Comment: Well just add ! and space.

Comment: @Stilgar why yes that would be what iv tried but all I get is Unrecognized escape sequence \_.

Comment: You don't want that `@` or the single quotes here. Now they are part of the regex.

Comment: @Hans Kesting thanks, ok I current now have this 'ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+ !_ $"' which is now loading the form but as soon as a letter or number is inputted it errors

Comment: @HansKesting in fact any character that's not a space is shows the error thanks Mike

Comment: @Mikey - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+ !_ ` is: one or more letters or digits, followed by space, '!', '_', space. You need the extra characters *inside* the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way is to use this `^[a-zA-Z0-9!_ ]+$` you needed to add the characters inside your []

Comment: Thanks @AlanMorton2.0 same as the other answer but yes this works thanks mike

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9!_ ]+$
```

Add the appropriate symbols inside the character set.

Comment: Hi Thanks, will this disallow characters like ë É å ?

Comment: Yes but keep in mind that it will also disallow other alphabets like Cyrillic or Greek